# How to remove duplicates from millions of rows of data in pyspark dataframe, using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, duplicates, azure-synapse

The Code below is working well and the output I get is:
[Dataframe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfffW.png)

the sample schema example I have: [Sample Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwLlo.png)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

#Flatten array of structs and structs
def flatten(df):
   # compute Complex Fields (Lists and Structs) in Schema   
   complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
   while len(complex_fields)!=0:
      col_name=list(complex_fields.keys())[0]
    
      # if StructType then convert all sub element to columns.
      # i.e. flatten structs
      if (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == StructType):
         expanded = [col(col_name+'.'+k).alias(col_name+'_'+k) for k in [ n.name for n in  complex_fields[col_name]]]
         df=df.select("*", *expanded).drop(col_name)
    
      # if ArrayType then add the Array Elements as Rows using the explode function
      # i.e. explode Arrays
      elif (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == ArrayType):    
         df=df.withColumn(col_name,explode_outer(col_name))
    
      # recompute remaining Complex Fields in Schema       
      complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType)
                             for field in df.schema.fields
                             if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
   return df

flattened_df = flatten(df)
df1 = flattened_df
df1 = df1.select(
    df1["_source_Vrvirksomhed_cvrNummer"],
    df1["_source_Vrvirksomhed_deltagerRelation_organisationer_medlemsData_attributter_vaerdier_vaerdi"],
    df1["_source_Vrvirksomhed_deltagerRelation_organisationer_medlemsData_attributter_vaerdier_periode_gyldigFra"],
    df1["_source_Vrvirksomhed_deltagerRelation_organisationer_medlemsData_attributter_vaerdier_periode_gyldigTil"] )
df2 = df1.filter(df1._source_Vrvirksomhed_deltagerRelation_organisationer_medlemsData_attributter_vaerdier_vaerdi == "REVISION")
df2 = df2[(df2._source_Vrvirksomhed_cvrNummer == 10088437)]
```

However, from the image which is in the link above. You can see I have lots of duplicates. I want to remove the duplicates in accurate and fast manner

I have tried

- df2.dropduplicates()
- df2.distinct()
- repartitioning the dataframe
- caching the the dataframe

They all have taken over 20+ minutes to run without any successes.

Is someone able to help me remove duplicates easily millions of rows of data

Answer (score 0):

dropDuplicates is the way to remove duplicates, and yes this is slow. So a better way is to not create duplicates in the first place. Perhaps you can limit the duplicates by first calling array_distinct before exploding? This is all highly dependent on your input data.

Comment: I tried this. However, the same issue is happening. My Input data is a complex deeply nested json file with lots of arrays and structs. 

I have attached the sample schema in the original post